# Responsive image gallery with each image accessible with an anchor link

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, responsive-design

I've found plenty of great responsive image gallery's such as [Flexslider](http://www.woothemes.com/flexslider/), but the none of them give you the following functionally:

To have each image have it's own anchor tag, that can be accessed directly via the URL. For example: http://www.website.com/gallery#image-of-a-dog

What I'd really like to have is a gallery with thumbnails where each thumbnail will link and slide the right image via an anchor link.

I know the [Anything Slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/#&panel1-1) can do this, but it's not responsive.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Comment: You could do this with server-side scripting by using query variables. Is that an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an example using [`jQuery cycle`](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle).

but you can use it with any plugin that let's you choose from which slide to start.

let's say you have a gallery of 10 photos, and when a photo is clicked you
append the number to the url, let's say you clicked on photo `3` thus the url
will be `/gallery#3`.

so you need to get this number:

```
 var num = location.pathname.split('#')[1];
 if (!num) num = 0; // default to starting slide.
 $('#gallery').cycle({ startingSlide: parseInt(num) });
```

hope this helps.